# Fontsize specified with fontspec is different from what Adobe Pro thinks

Tags: fonts, fontspec, fontsize

I have written a document using fontspec, for compilation with xelatex or lulatex, that specifies an 11pt font. However, when I then check the font size with Acrobat Pro, it says the font size is 10.87 for a Times font and 10.91 for Arial. This is an important difference in my case. I can fix it with a bit of magnification, but I am wondering what is going on. Something similar actually goes on with regular pdflatex sometimes. Is there a bug somewhere? Are font sizes a little arbitrary? Here is an MWE, and thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Scale=1]{Arial}
\setmainfont[Scale=1]{Times}
\begin{document}
Now is the winter of my \textsf{discontent with fonts.} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes the notion of a font size is a bit vage. Beside this, the option `11pt` loads a `\@xipt` sized font, and `\@xipt` is defined as `\def\@xipt{10.95}` in latex..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `11pt` option sets the default font size to
10.95 TeX points (`pt`)
which is
10.909 = 10.95*72/72.27 Postscript Points (`bp`)

Comment: Thanks.  Why is there a difference (if that is easily explained)/ Also, do you mean it sets the default font size to 10.95 (not 11.95) TeX points?

Comment: @GeoffV sorry fixed the 10.95 typo.  Knuth chose to use a unit very close to the traditional "printers point" using the nicely palindromic 72.27pt to the inch.  Adobe, around the same time defined PostScript and defined a nominal "point" of 72 points to the inch.  TeX calls these big points (bp)  roll on 50 years and most of the rest of the digital world followed PostScript terminology, it is what it is....