# Latex + amsart + times font size

Tags: fonts, fontsize, amsart

I am writing a pdf document in LaTeX using package amsart. The specifications for the document require that it be in Times New Roman font and 11 point font size.

I have therefore included:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{times}
```

at the start of my document.

However, I was told by someone on the receiving end that when they opened the pdf in Adobe Acrobat Pro and looked at the "edit" feature, Adobe claims that the font size is "10.91".

Can anyone give me some advice on fixing this? (Let us take for granted that I understand the silliness of insisting that there is a meaningful difference between 10.91 and 11 point font and focus on the technical issue.)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This was asked the other day, I'll find a link but 11pt option selects a 10.95pt font which is 10.95*72/72.27 PostScript points

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623796/1090

Comment: Thank you for the link. I don't see any suggestion there for how to fix the problem. (Naively asking amsart to use 11.1 font size does not work.) Do you have any ideas?

Comment: you could do `\let\oldnormalsize\normalsize\renewcommand\normalsize{\oldnormalsize\fontsize{11bp}{13bp}\selectfont}`

Comment: Thanks! I can't really tell if it worked, but I will submit and see what happens. Can you tell me what this did?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `fontsize` package.

If I do

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart} % but any class is the same
\usepackage[fontsize=11bp]{fontsize}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

abc def $123$ 123

\expandafter\show\the\font

\end{document}
```

I get on the console

```
\T1/ntxtlf/m/n/11.04124=select font ntx-Regular-tlf-t1 at 11.04124pt
```

and 11.04124pt is precisely 11bp (that is, what Adobe thinks 11 points is).

I also tested, with XeLaTeX,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart} % but any class is the same
\usepackage[fontsize=11bp]{fontsize}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

abc def $123$ 123

\expandafter\show\the\font

\end{document}
```

and the console reports

```
\TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/11.04124=select font "Times New Roman/OT:script=latn
;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;" at 11.04124pt.
```